# como Pasar datos de un componente otro en la funcion onclick

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

tengo 2 componentes funcionales y quiero pasarle el valor de un atributo al otro componente pero cuando lo hago se pasa undefined

```
import React from 'react'

export const Componete1 = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <a src="http://.." onClick={(e) => <Componete2 src={e.target.getAttribute("src")} />}></a>
        </div>
    )
}

import React from 'react'

export const Componente2 = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={props.src}></img>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas intentando renderizar el `Componente2` en el `OnClick`, no funciona así, deberias tener un componente padre, que controlará con un `hook` la imagen del `Componente2`:

ComponentePadre:

```
import React from 'react'

export const ComponentePadre = () => {
    const[imgSrc,setImgSrc] = useState(null);
    return (
        <>
          <Componente1 onClickHandler={(img) => setImgSrc(img)} />
          {imgSrc && <Componente2 imgSrc={imgSrc} />}
        </>
    )
}
```

Componente1:

```
import React from 'react'

export const Componente1 = ({onClickHandler}) => {
    return (
        <div>
        <a src="http://.." onClick={(e) => onClickHandler(e.target.getAttribute("src"))} />}></a>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Componente2:

```
import React from 'react'

export const Componente2 = ({imgSrc}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={imgSrc}></img>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, solucione mi problema con esto

Comment: @CristianMendoza si la respuesta fue útil, recuerda marcarla como correcta :D